# how to access the data from object and get it in out component?

Tags: reactjs

how to access this data

```
{"rahulkesarvani959":true,"jogendra":true,"sahebali":true,"trinav":true,"zeeshan":true,"athiselvam":true,"shantanu":true,"shashi88988":true,"govind":true,"abhilash":true,"akashsaroj7180":true,"khaled":true,"vaibhav":true,"ajay":true,"aashish":true,"sagar":true,"sushil":true,"vishalkmbl555":true,"amar":true,"brajesh07gautam08":true,"del3vnf":true,"del2vnf":true,"aalokkyadav9988":true}
```

i have made the boy variable global but i am not able get the values in render function.

```
let boy = [];
 componentWillMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://freshvnf-api.firebaseio.com/tracked-locations.json?shallow=true")
      .then(resp => {
        if (resp.status === 200) {
          this.boy = _.keys(resp.data);
          console.log(this.boy);
        }
        else {
          Modal.error({
            title: 'Error!',
            content: resp.message,
          });
        }
      });
  }

 render() {
    console.log(this.boy);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Layout className="dashboardLayout">
```

Comment: Heyy,welcome to the stackoverflow you should post your code in proper format

Answer (score 0):

You should have a state in your component instead of the global variable. Then when you get the response from API, you could do a setState() which gets that data.

See the example code in React's [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html).